# How to track data changes in one spreadsheet with App Script in other spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I probably got quite a challenge:
Tracking data changes and recording 'comments' made in the main spreadsheet with Apps Script in other spreadsheets.

I have one [data spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RfSk4QDb99GPG0akv2qXoHMo1Y1pepts1emir5RHhUE) which has rows with data sets.
For each data row in this main sheet another 'history'-spreadsheet exists (e.g. [history – First name spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL_ApdPe04OnyTbwuHPpuqyIgBD6yQw0-moOP4cXnB0)). Those 'history'-sheets should (1) track data changes and (2) record 'comments' for the corresponding row.

---

**For example**

(1) If someone changes a value in row 2 in the [data spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RfSk4QDb99GPG0akv2qXoHMo1Y1pepts1emir5RHhUE), App Script should insert a row in the corresponding spreadsheet (in this case [history – First name spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL_ApdPe04OnyTbwuHPpuqyIgBD6yQw0-moOP4cXnB0)) between row 2 and 3 (it's always between those two rows) and add information like in row 4, 6 or 7.

(2) If someone enters a 'comment' in the [data spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RfSk4QDb99GPG0akv2qXoHMo1Y1pepts1emir5RHhUE) in one of the rows in column F, App Script again should insert a row in the corresponding spreadsheet between row 2 and 3 and add the comment like in row 3 or 5 in the [history – First name spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL_ApdPe04OnyTbwuHPpuqyIgBD6yQw0-moOP4cXnB0). And last but not least delete the comment in the data spreadsheet.

---

I searched a lot but did not find anything helpful.
Unfortunately I am not a programmer.
Any help would be appreciated!

Best wishes,
Alex

Comment: 1. is simple: **Option A**: publish as webapp in the receiving spreadsheet, and forward the `onEdit` event object captured by a function in the original spreadsheet that has an installed `onEdit` trigger. You'll need to run the webapp as yourself, and allow anonymous access.  Probably best to gate the call to `UrlFetch` with range checks. **Option B**: give anyone who makes changes to the source spreadsheet edit access to the "tracker workbook", and make the source spreadsheet's onEdit-triggered function open the other workbook remotely (via SpreadsheetApp.openById), adding the necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar in Apps Script with an onEdit() event. You could change it to add the user's comment before it appends to the other sheet.

```
function appendLine() {
    var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    var spreadsheetTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var lastUpdatedString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    if (s.getName() == "Workload") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 14) { //checks the column
            var status = r.getValue();
            var note = r.offset(0, -1);
            var noteValue = note.getValue()
            var delivery = r.offset(0, -5);
            var deliveryValue = delivery.getValue().toString();
        }

        // Validating fields are filled in
        if (status == "Complete") {
            var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
            if (noteValue == '') { // if no note is entered, stop script with message box
                var noStatus = ui.alert(
                    'Warning!',
                    'Please enter notation before choosing Complete.',
                    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
                r.setValue('')
                return;
            }

            // get array values
            var array = [lastUpdatedString, sessionEmail, deliveryValue, noteValue]          

            // insert at row 2 of destination, so newest note is always at the top and found in the index(match())   
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
            var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historical Notes Sheet");
            var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
            lock.waitLock(30000);
            try {
                var index = 2;
                pasteSheet.insertRowBefore(index).getRange(index, 1, 1, array.length).setValues([array]);
                SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            } finally {
                lock.releaseLock();
            }

            // clear response row
            note.setValue('')
            r.setValue('')
        }
    }
}
```